# How to get the branch target and type of branch of committed ins in gem5 for O3 CPU?

Tags: gem5

I am implementing a prefetcher on gem5. It requires to know the RAS state, branch type (call or return ) and branch target of a committed instruction. I am new to the gem5 environment. How can I get this info to the prefectcher?

Comment: Also ask on the gem5-users mailing list.